# How to display multiple results in Crystal Reports horizontally?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm needing help with displaying my 8 results in a single horizontal configuration. I have a work order that has a table with a check list. The check list is a pass or fail for the 8 questions. Each `CAT` has its own code that reads `IF {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT}='one of the TEST Name' THEN {@pass-fail}` I set the same code for each of the 8 test groups

When I pull the data and group it by the `WO` its repeating 8 times with each line with a pass or fail in the details:

[image: stair pattern]

If I suppress the details and put it in the group footer I only get the last result:

[image: single]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although such reports are better manageable as Cross-Tab / Pivot-Table. As far as I know Crystal Reports (upto version 9, can't say about later versions) does not support non-numeric pivots. So such cases can be handled better at Sql pivot level.

Even though, for a fixed level requirements such as 8 questions in your case following approach can be used. You need to create three formula fields `f_Reset`, `f_Concat` and `f_Print` and set their values as follows:

1. `f_Reset`: Initialize default result as `fail`

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   stringVar Q1 := "fail";
   stringVar Q2 := "fail";
   stringVar Q3 := "fail";
   stringVar Q4 := "fail";
   stringVar Q5 := "fail";
   stringVar Q6 := "fail";
   stringVar Q7 := "fail";
   stringVar Q8 := "fail";
   stringVar st_Final := "";
   ```
2. `f_Concat`: Check results for all questions

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 1 Name' then stringVar Q1 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 2 Name' then stringVar Q2 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 3 Name' then stringVar Q3 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 4 Name' then stringVar Q4 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 5 Name' then stringVar Q5 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 6 Name' then stringVar Q6 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 7 Name' then stringVar Q7 := {@pass-fail};
   if {F_CHECKLISTS.CHK_TEXT} = 'Test 8 Name' then stringVar Q8 := {@pass-fail};
   ```
3. `f_Print`: Prepare final display result

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   stringVar st_Final := stringVar Q1 + "    " + stringVar Q2 + "    " + stringVar Q3 + "    " + stringVar Q4 + "    " + stringVar Q5 + "    " + stringVar Q6 + "    " + stringVar Q7 + "    " + stringVar Q8;
   ```

Next, perform following steps:

1. Insert a group into your report by any one of the common fields (e.g. `WO` as in your second screenshot).
2. Place `f_Reset` formula field in the Group Header
3. Place `f_Concat` formula field in the Details section
4. Place and format all other fields from `Open` to `Area Description` in the report footer as they were in the Detail section (*simply a copy of Details section without 8 result fields*)
5. Place the `f_Print` formula field in the Group Footer section and stretch it along all 8 result titles (*single* `f_print` *formula field for all 8 results*)
6. `Suppress` Group Header
7. `Suppress` Details section

The basic idea is to concatenate all results to a string and then show it in one go. You may need to adjust concatenated space in `f_Print` i.e. `+ "    "` to align the values below 8 result titles.

Comment: Thank You for you response haraman that is working somewhat, but in the f_print formula its not passing the value of st_Final?  Q1-Q8  is looking for a value of some kind

Comment: I didn't get your point: *Q1-Q8 is looking for a value of some kind*. Isn't it how `pass` or `fail` is determined?

Comment: Yes **{pass-fail}** is  written like **if {F_CHECK_RESULTS.CLR_PASSED} = 'YES' then 'pass' else 'fail'**  but when I add the code to **f_Print**   crystal is telling me its looking for a value ?

Comment: Then just explicitly declare type of each Q1-Q8 as `stringVar` Q1-Q8 as modified above. i.e. `stringVar st_Final := stringVar Q1 + "    " + stringVar Q2 + "    " + stringVar Q3 ...`

Comment: Thank You so much for your help it works just the way i need it to